# Jmeter synchronize requests in slaves

Tags: jmeter

I am running test in distributed mode with 1 master and 2 slaves.
One slave generating 99 users load and other one generating 1 user load(Reading the user count from properties file).
I am using synchronize timer and setting the Group by value in it to 100 as I want all the 100 requests(99+1) to execute together. It does not run properly, probably because jmeter executes the test plan separately in both the slaves. So, I am reading the Group by value for synchronize timer from user.properties file in both the slaves, for slave 1 the value is 99 and for other it is 1. It executes my plan but the second slave requests are not synchronized with the slave one. 
How can I synchronize the requests in both the slaves.

Answer (score 1):

Your test plan is not very well designed, you cannot reach this level of synchronisation as JMeter slaves are totally independent beasts therefore they don't know anything about each other. I can suggest the following options:

1. Single Thread Group + [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller):

   - Put all requests into a single Thread Group
   - Use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) combination to tell only first thread to read properties file like:

     - If Controller, condition: `${__threadNum} == 1`

       - Sampler to read properties file
2. Single Thread Group + [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
3. Different Thread Groups:

   You can use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) to ensure that your `99 users load` will be executed as soon as `1 user load` will finish.